# View queue of PENDING jobs?

Tags: cluster-computing, sungridengine

I have submitted a bunch of jobs to a SGE cluster. `qstat -f` shows the queue of running jobs, and then a list of PENDING jobs. I would like to know the queue requested for PENDING jobs when they were submitted. How can I gather this info?

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
qstat -f -j 3150671 | grep hard_queue_list
```